# Play a Video from MemoryStream, Using FFMpeg

Tags: delphi, ffmpeg

I'm having a hard time, searching how to play a video file from a TMemoryStream (or a similar buffer in memory) using FFMpeg. I've seen many things, including UltraStarDX, expensive FFMpeg components for Delphi and so on.

One component called [FFMpeg Vcl Player](http://www.flashavconverter.com/content/ffmpeg-vcl-player-delphi) claims to play video formats from a memory stream. I downloaded the trial version and I guess it uses CircularBuffer.pas for that matter (maybe).

Does any one know how to do this?

Edit:
Now the better question is how to play an encrypted video file, using FFMpeg or similar libraries.

Comment: Just an idea: could you pass a named pipe to the file-in of FFMPeg? something like `\\.\pipe\NamedPipeToMyData` and then write from the memory stream into the other end as soon as FFMpeg connects.

Comment: @StijnSanders I've also tried named pipes. To be honest, I couldn't get a named pipe to work. Can you point me to some example that creates a named pipe and write something to it?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://sourceforge.net/p/xxm/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Delphi/cgi/ xxmCGI is a 'small' exe that pipes the std-in/out to a named pipe, xxmHost 'hosts' the named pipe and handles the requests.

Comment: Correction: xxmCGI connects to xxmHost's named pipe just to get handles for unnamed pipes to forward std-in/out to/from.

Comment: So, is it suitable for my purpose? I need to write contents of a Stream or a buffer.

Comment: How about playing through VLC? It has Delphi headers and examples are available.

Comment: @KromStern, does VLC support playing from a TMemoryStream?

Comment: @Delphi.Boy: Sure, we even used VLC to play live streams from surveillance cameras.

Comment: @Delphi.Boy: You might want to accept the answer to this question and start a separate new one about encrypted videos ;)

Comment: try this. worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49023124/extracting-resourcesi-e-mp4-file-from-bpl-packages?noredirect=1#comment85056120_49023124

Answer (score 20):

To play video from memory stream, you can use custom `AVIOContext`.

```cpp
static const int kBufferSize = 4 * 1024;

class my_iocontext_private
{
private:
    my_iocontext_private(my_iocontext_private const &);
    my_iocontext_private& operator = (my_iocontext_private const &);

public:
    my_iocontext_private(IInputStreamPtr inputStream)
       : inputStream_(inputStream)
       , buffer_size_(kBufferSize)
       , buffer_(static_cast<unsigned char*>(::av_malloc(buffer_size_))) {
    ctx_ = ::avio_alloc_context(buffer_, buffer_size_, 0, this,
           &my_iocontext_private::read, NULL, &my_iocontext_private::seek); 
    }

    ~my_iocontext_private() { 
        ::av_free(ctx_);
        ::av_free(buffer_); 
    }

    void reset_inner_context() { ctx_ = NULL; buffer_ = NULL; }

    static int read(void *opaque, unsigned char *buf, int buf_size) {
        my_iocontext_private* h = static_cast<my_iocontext_private*>(opaque);
        return h->inputStream_->Read(buf, buf_size); 
    }

    static int64_t seek(void *opaque, int64_t offset, int whence) {
        my_iocontext_private* h = static_cast<my_iocontext_private*>(opaque);

        if (0x10000 == whence)
            return h->inputStream_->Size();

        return h->inputStream_->Seek(offset, whence); 
    }

    ::AVIOContext *get_avio() { return ctx_; }

    private:
       IInputStreamPtr inputStream_; // abstract stream interface, You can adapt it to TMemoryStream  
       int buffer_size_;
       unsigned char * buffer_;  
       ::AVIOContext * ctx_;
   };


   //// ..........

   /// prepare input stream:
   IInputStreamPtr inputStream = MyCustomCreateInputStreamFromMemory();

   my_iocontext_private priv_ctx(inputStream);
   AVFormatContext * ctx = ::avformat_alloc_context();
   ctx->pb = priv_ctx.get_avio();

   int err = avformat_open_input(&ctx, "arbitrarytext", NULL, NULL);
   if (err < 0) 
       return -1;

   //// normal usage of ctx
   //// avformat_find_stream_info(ctx, NULL);
   //// av_read_frame(ctx, &pkt); 
   //// etc..
```

Comment: Well, I use Delphi and you've posted CPP. Can you provide more details please?

Comment: Can you please provide more info?

Comment: Downvote, the question is asking about Delphi, not C++.

Comment: Also this did not work for me in C++ with the current API.

Comment: Works well with `FFmpeg.AutoGen`, I literally rewrote your code to C#. Thanks!

Comment: where does IInputStreamPtr come from?

Comment: @djomlastic can you post the C# code please?

Answer (score 1):

You can waste your time rewriting FFMPEG from C++ to Delphi, or mess with wrapper libraries.

Or if you're just interested in playing a video in Delphi, then check out Mitov's VideoLab components.

http://www.mitov.com/products/videolab#components

Comment: It doesn't seem to support playing from a memory stream, does it?

Comment: what doesn't? If you think about it, most video files are REALLY BIG, and a memory-based stream isn't typically advisable. What kind of video file would only be an in-memory file, with no disk image? Sometimes things aren't supported because they just don't make a whole lot of sense, even though people can certainly come up with odd reasons to do so.

Comment: Well, I need to play custom encrypted video files. So, I guessed I could decrypt it to memory and play from there. Is it odd?

Answer (score 1):

If you want play Stream from memory you can make a virtual memory. I suggest [BoxedAppSdk](http://www.boxedapp.com/boxedappsdk/).

This will help you to make a virtual drive with virtual files that you can write on it and then give the virtual path to the player component that you have.

**BoxedApp** is not free but it is really awesome and very simple in use!