# FFmpeg avformat_open_input with memory located file

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, pcm, networkstream

I want to decode an internet-audiostream, but I don't want to write the data to disk, so the data is located in the memory only.

But when I want to decode data to raw-data, I must initialise the format-context and so I need to use avformat_open_input. But these function needs a detailed location of the file.

Have anyone a solution, how I can get my memory located data into the format-context to decode this data to a raw data?

Answer (score 4):

You must create custom `AVIOContext`.

For details, see my answer to [Play a Video from MemoryStream, Using FFMpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785254/play-a-video-from-memorystream-using-ffmpeg)

Answer (score -2):

You don't need a file, just use your internet-audiostream url to open. like this:

```
AVFormatContext *ic = avformat_alloc_context();
err = avformat_open_input(&ic, "rtmp://www.something.com/a.mp4", NULL, NULL);
```