# Extracting Resources(i.e .MP4 file) from .BPL packages

Tags: delphi

I have written a program to load .mp4 files in .bpl packages through .rc compilation.
After that i created a frame to load the above compiled .bpl from an exe.
But while calling TResourceStream from the exe, this function is unable to extract data from bpl.

I have made .RES file where i have included my .mp4 video and used the resource in the bpl section in unit.

My code goes here:

First firm where i load bpl file

```
procedure TForm4.LoadFrame(Name, ModuleName: String);
begin
     PackageModule := LoadPackage('C:\Users\Shishir\VideoPack.bpl');
      AClass := GetClass('TFrame_VideoGrabber');


     if AClass <> nil then
     begin
          with TComponentClass(AClass).Create(Application) as TCustomFrame do
          begin
               Parent := Panel1;
               Align := alClient;
               Show;
          end;
     end;
end;
```

This part where i want to play .mp4 file
i am having problem with extracting data from loaded .bpl

```
procedure TFrame_VideoGrabber.BitBtn3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  rStream: TResourceStream;
  fStream: TFileStream;
  fname: string;
 begin
  fname := ExtractFileDir(Paramstr(0))+'vid.mp4';
  rStream := TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, 'Intro', RT_RCDATA) ;
 try
   fStream := TFileStream.Create(fname, fmCreate) ;
   try
    fStream.CopyFrom(rStream, 0) ;
   finally
    fStream.Free;
   end;
  finally
   rStream.Free;
  end;
  {this part plays the mp4}
  WindowsMediaPlayer1.url:=fname;
 end;
```

I am getting this error message:
 EresNotFound with message 'Resource Intro not Found'

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: can i extract .mp4 file from bpl in my Frame_VideoGrabber unit

Comment: Use a resource stream. If you have problems with the code debug it. Don't tell us that it doesn't work without also showing your debugging efforts, any error messages etc. Like so many of today's programmers it looks like you don't know how to, or choose not to, debug. You can't become a programmer like this.

Comment: There is EresNotFound with message 'Resource Intro not Found'

Comment: Are you sure that's the error message verbatim. Do some debugging. Use a resource viewer to check the resource name and type in the compiled module. Check that HInstance refers to the correct module. Check also that fname has what you expect. Finally, it's probably a bad idea to embed movies like this. It forces address space to be reserved that you never actually use. Distribute the movies as external files wherever you distribute the package. Why are you even using runtime packages?

Comment: I do not want to distribute the videos . I need videos to be played from my software only.

Comment: Well, if you distribute the package then anybody can simply extract the movies and do what they want with them. What are the file sizes of these movies anyway?

Comment: Is it possible to extract resource file from .BPL files. I successfully extracted resource from .EXE. But i am having error while doing it with .BPL file. maximum 50mb size of data of .mp4 file

Comment: Yes it is possible. You are doing it wrong. You ignored all my comments about debugging. Your entire approach is a total waste of time. Distribute movies files separately.

Comment: Anyway, as for the question, it's a dupe. I was hoping to persuade you of the value of debugging but it looks like I failed. Since you use runtime packages,  HInstance, will represent the rtl package. The dupe explains what to do. It's still a pointless task. You will put pressure on process memory address space and anyone who has the package can trivially obtain the video files.

Comment: fname is correct as i expected. but RT_RCDATA is nil. I think i should use other methods than doing this. TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, 'Intro', RT_RCDATA) ;

Comment: No, `RT_RCDATA` is not `nil`. It looks like a pointer, but it's actually a special sentinel value. The problem is as I described, and the solution is given at the dupe.

Comment: GetModuleHandle. does the trick. thank you very much @DavidHeffernan .I am very much thankful.

Comment: Wrong solution.